# How can I run a code in Gin framework on https

Tags: go, http, ssl, go-gin

I'm running my code on port 8080, but I need to run the gin code on ssl. Here's the code:

```
r.POST("/banktransactionstatus", func(c *gin.Context) {
    //input stuct
    type RequestData struct {
        PrivateTransactionReference string `json:"private transaction reference"`
    }

    inputData := RequestData{}

    // Bind the request body to the inputData struct
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&inputData); err != nil {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"message": "Invalid request data"})
        return
    }
    // Define the XML request data (this is just for illustration)
    
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Error reading response"})
        return
    }

    // Unmarshal the XML response into a struct
    var responseData ResponseData
    if err := xml.Unmarshal(responseXML, &responseData); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Error unmarshaling XML"})
        return
    }

    // Construct a JSON response using the extracted values
    jsonResponse := gin.H{
        "Transaction status":        responseData.TransactionStatus,
        "Transaction Reference":     responseData.TransactionReference,
        "Status":                    responseData.Status,
        "StatusCode":                responseData.StatusCode,
        "StatusMessage":             responseData.StatusMessage,
        "message":                   responseData.Message,
        "Error Message":             responseData.ErrorMessage,
        "MNOTransactionReferenceId": responseData.MNOTransactionReferenceId,
    }

    // Return the JSON response
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, jsonResponse)
})
r.Run(":8080")
```

when I try to run on port 443, I get an error telling me that the port is already in use. Anyone please help me out.

Comment: You need to either run it on a different port or stop whatever else is already running on port 443.

Comment: Cant I share port 443?

Comment: @JoelSwakiseTheDancer no you cannot, it's managed by os and not your app or golang, Another application is binding 443 port, mostly main website of the machine which can be accessed in browser using: `https://your.server.com` , try openning the site and recognize the application, you can use this script on linux `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN| grep 443`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `RunTLS`:

> RunTLS attaches the router to a http.Server and starts listening and serving HTTPS (secure) requests.
> It is a shortcut for http.ListenAndServeTLS(addr, certFile, keyFile, router)
> Note: this method will block the calling goroutine indefinitely unless an error happens.

```
err := r.RunTLS(":8080", "server.pem", "server.key")
```